# how to consume Nest array with out displaying the duplicates in angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, ionic-framework

I am getting the below response

```
 (3) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0
0
{Current: 121, Previous: 102, Variation: 19, VariationPercent: 18.63, VariationColor: "#008000", …}
1
{Current: 103, Previous: 108, Variation: -5, VariationPercent: -4.63, VariationColor: "#B23921", …}
2
{Current: 133, Previous: 113, Variation: 20, VariationPercent: 17.7, VariationColor: "#008000", …}
3
{Current: 155, Previous: 132, Variation: 23, VariationPercent: 17.42, VariationColor: "#008000", …}

1

0
{Current: 0, Previous: 0, Variation: 0, VariationPercent: 0, VariationColor: "#008000", …}
1
{Current: 0, Previous: 15, Variation: -15, VariationPercent: -100, VariationColor: "#008000", …}
2
{Current: 30, Previous: 0, Variation: 30, VariationPercent: 3000, VariationColor: "#B23921", …}
3
{Current: 190, Previous: 45, Variation: 145, VariationPercent: 322.22, VariationColor: "#B23921", …}

2

0
{Current: 0, Previous: 0, Variation: 0, VariationPercent: 0, VariationColor: "#008000", …}
1
{Current: 6326, Previous: 3962, Variation: 2364, VariationPercent: 59.67, VariationColor: "#008000", …}
2
{Current: 3655, Previous: 3236, Variation: 419, VariationPercent: 12.95, VariationColor: "#008000", …}
3
{Current: 4848, Previous: 5040, Variation: -192, VariationPercent: -3.81, VariationColor: "#B23921", …}
```

previously i used to consume the nested array using this logic

```
var resultList=[];

   ///////////
   for (var key in result) {
     if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       resultList.push(result[key]);
     }
   }
   console.log(resultList);
   this.resultData=resultList;
   console.log(this.resultData);
 },error=>{

   loading.dismiss();
   toast.present();
   console.log(error)})
  }
```

Now what happend is suppose if there is an item  named mobile in array 1,array 2,array 3 it is displaying thrice the below is the sample response im getting here **i m trying to sort/ group the result so that repeated items has to be displayed once not thrice**

[image: below is the responce im getting when im consuming the above data]

Comment: please correctly format the code

Comment: Use trackby property of ngForOf for displaying unique elements.

Comment: @Ajay for grouping it works ?